# Não consigo Atualizar projeto spring no heroku com o git

Tags: git, heroku

Sigo os seguintes passos mas não funciona:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "mensagem"
git push heroku master
```

> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git init
>   Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/Adriano/Documents/deoliveira-embal/deoliveira-embal/.git/
>
> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git add .
>
> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git commit -m  "correção prorpriedades projeto"
>   On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean
>
> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git push heroku master
>   fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
>
> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git status
>   On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean
>
> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git remote
>   origin

Comment: Vc recebe alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Por favor, adicione o output recebido após o útimo comando.

Comment: Posta a saída o comando, **git status**  e **git remote**. Acredito que vc esteja na branch master, e não tenha configurado um repositório remoto.

Comment: fiz comando git status e git remote esta no log

Comment: Vc não fez login no heroku antes de usar o comando *create app* do heroku? Ou então não utilizou o comando na mesma pasta do repositório git? Tô com uma resposta quase pronta. Se puder responder, te ajudo a resolver e eu publico.

Comment: Olá. Minha resposta foi suficiente para resolver seu problema? Ou ainda está precisando de algo? Caso tenha sido. Pode aceitá-la?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

- Ou vc adiciona a url remota do repositório [manualmente](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Essencial-Trabalhando-com-Remotos) com o comando

> `git remote add [nomecurto] [url]`

desta maneira,  `git remote add`**`heroku [url-do-app]`**

**OBS**: A url remota pode ser encontrada em **Heroku Git URL**[image: aqui]

---

- Ou vc refaz os passos anteriores de criação do diretório de trabalho, dos arquivos, login no heroku, mas utilizando o comando `heroku create nome-do-app` **APÓS** ter logado e inicializado o repositório git, assim

  ---

  `git init`
  `git add .`
  `git commit -m "Commit Inicial"`
  `heroku create ptso-hello-world  //OBS O COMANDO PRECISA SER NO MESMO DIRETÓRIO DO REPOSITÓRIO GIT`
  `git push heroku master`

  ---

### Uma pequena explicação sobre os comandos

> `git init`

Serve para inicializar um repositório git que se deseja fazer o controle de versão.

A saída

> C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git init
>   Reinitialized existing Git repository in
>   C:/Users/Adriano/Documents/deoliveira-embal/deoliveira-embal/.git/

Demonstra que o repositório já existia e foi reinicializado, aqui está ok.

Em

> `C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\deoliveira-embal\deoliveira-embal>git add .`

Você adiciona os arquivos do repositório recém inicializado para o controle de versão. Aqui está ok.

Aqui

> `git commit -m "correção prorpriedades projeto"`

Você cria um novo "snapshot" dos arquivos modificados para que seja feito o controle de versão, para que seja possível voltar a este ponto, ver as modificações posteriores, anteriores, etc.

A mensagem de retorno

> On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with **'origin/master'**.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

Significa que já havia commitado todas as alterações nos arquivos e não há alterações novas. Uma coisa a se notar (que está em negrito) é a branch e o repositório remoto a que se refere, o repositório **origin**.

A saída do comando

> `git push heroku master`

dá uma dica do problema,

> fatal: **'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository** fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct
>   access rights and the repository exists.

significa que o repositório remoto de nome "heroku" não existe. Como pode ser visto no  livro [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Essencial-Trabalhando-com-Remotos) para trabalhar com repositórios remoto precisamos adicionar a url remota e dar um nome para trabalharmos localmente. Quando clonamos, do github por exemplo, o nome **origin** é dado automaticamente.

Quando vamos trabalhar com o heroku, ele também dá um nome local para o repositório remoto automaticamente com o nome de **heroku**, mas para isso precisamos ter utilizado o comando `heroku create` no diretório que **contém nosso repositório git**.

Ao fazer isto, o "heroku" adiciona a **url do repositório remoto do heroku** sob o nome **heroku** para trabalhar localmente, de forma automática.